# Finding the length.

Tags: geometry

[image: Question]

*Solution:*

(i) circumference $= 125.6$cm

(ii) arc length CS $= 10.47$cm

(iii) I’m stuck in this part. I can’t find **CT** no matter what I do.

Comment: Have you studied trigonometry? Or more specifically, do you know the side length ratios of a triangle with angles of 30°, 60° and 90°?

Comment: I assume $S\hat OC$ is arc $SOC$?

Comment: $ST=OS(1-\cos30^\circ)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***HINT(s)***

Notice that $\triangle COS$ is equilateral with $OC=OS=R$ and that $OC$ is perpendicular to the ground, and thus to $CT$.

So $\angle OCS+\angle SCT=90$ so $\angle SCT=\cdots$.

But $\cos(\angle SCT)=\frac{CT}{CS}$.

Comment: I know till that part. It’s just I can’t find anything afterwards.

Comment: @Lofle Now, after the edit?